# How to use visual studio for GitHub actions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, github-actions, installshield

We have a jenkins server setup in AWS on an ubuntu machine.

Created two machines on windows server 2012 and each having visual studio enterprise edition installed and license using single signon on those machines.

And on second machine we have installshield installed and that is a nodelocked license.

For every build these machines are used and at the end installshield will be used to create a setup file and synced to onedrive.

How to migrate this setup to GitHub actions and use onetime runners(every time) instead of fixed runners.

Issue is, how the license will be managed with these runners and the visual studio installation also.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the Github Actions wiki for [migrating from jenkins](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/migrating-to-github-actions/migrating-from-jenkins-to-github-actions).
Github actions also has support for [self-hosted runners](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/about-self-hosted-runners), and there is also the [security hardening](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions) guidelines for managing signing keys.

If the software you need isn't [preinstalled](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#preinstalled-software), you can always use `apt` or setup scripts since you're already using Ubuntu on your current machine.

`apt` also doesn't require `sudo` on runners:

```yaml
- name: Install Dependencies
  run: |
       apt-get update && apt-get install -y ...
```

On the subject of visual studio, use the build tools instead of the full enterprise version - AFAIK there aren't any licensing issues with that, but you can find
On that note, I did find some interesting discussion about the license for using the full visual studio build tools on the [VSCode github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/95745), including a pretty good [breakdown](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/95745#issuecomment-625438641) of exactly where and how you can use them according to the license.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the reasons why I switched from InstallShield to WiX.  While you could have a step to install InstallShield (assuming you have admin)  you'd have to go to concurrent licensing instead of node locked.  All that ugliness goes away when you use FOSS tools instead of properietary DRM locked tools.